# Is it a bad idea to park a car in a shallow puddle for hours at a time?

Tags: tires

Just what the title asks.

The parking lot at my office is prone to light flooding after a good rain, and my car will typically be parked in a shallow puddle for a few hours (I drive home for lunch, so it's never parked more than 4ish hours at a time).

Is the standing water bad for the tires? Do I need to strategically be searching for a parking space on high ground?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: Huh? Can you give some explanation on that, @PeteCon?

Comment: Shallow meaning 0.5 inches or 6 inches? Does your car never sit in a puddle while you sleep?

Comment: Shallow meaning closer to 0.5 inches, but it really depends on how much it rains. I park on a sloped driveway at home, so this question only comes into play when I'm at work, @MonkeyZeus.

Comment: Water will not affect the rubber in any tangible capacity. You will replace the tires due to wear-and-tear long before you experience any bad effects from water. You are more prone to having the tires go bad due to [dry rot](https://evanstire.com/stop-rot-need-know-tire-dry-rot/). High water can cause an issue for your braking or suspension system because the metal would rust. 0.5 inches though?

Comment: Here's a forum about your question https://www.team-bhp.com/forum/tyre-alloy-wheel-section/93221-effect-parking-6-inches-rain-water.html

Comment: I've cleaned up this thread a bit. Let's everyone please keep things civil.

Comment: [It says here](https://www.chicagotribune.com/news/ct-xpm-1993-09-10-9309100286-story.html) that "if the tire has nicks or cuts that allow water to seep inside, the moisture evenutually will rust the steel belts or degrade the cords-or both." Not a complete answer though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If water does not reach the bottom of the wheels, the car will be fine. As another answer says, getting tires wet on the outside is not an issue.

If water reaches the bottom of the wheels, try to move the car to another spot. Persistent immersion in water can wear away wheel finish over time, and water can cause corrosion around valve stems.

Vehicles generally prefer a dry environment, but if the air is humid it doesn't really matter whether the vehicle is over a big puddle or not at this point as air humidity does more damage than water under the vehicle.

Answer (score 2):

The tyres are waterproof. They will not be harmed by getting wet.

Comment: It would really help if you cited some authoritative source supporting this statement.

Comment: @jwh20 I cite the real world. Have you ever seen a car tyre damaged by water? Discarded ones sit for years with water inside them. They are even used as fenders on boats.

Comment: And there are rubberlined tanks that hold water and various solutions  more efficiently than any metal - in the real world.

Answer (score -4):

Actually, it depends on the temperature of the puddle. Especially if you have old or profile tires, the cold water can speed up the process of deflating your tires. I live in the Canadian winters of Hamilton Ontario where I keep many cars on the lot and I make sure not to leave any tires in puddles overnight. If it's for a few hours in the day and the water isn't cold than its a different story and should be fine, like the others said so long as the water isn't getting inside the rims. The main concern should be the cold though.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you'd like to contribute to the site, then please do so, but don't add frivolous links into the answer, as we all know this is spam.